# Long range video transmition via WiFi

Tags: wifi

Basically what I am trying to do is to transmit a Video Stream of the Rapberry Pi Camera to my linux Computer. I want to use it as a FPV system for my R/C Plane.

I have brought a Rapsberry Pi Zero, an AlfaUS051NH with a 14dbi directional antenna and the Raspberry Camera 2.0.

On the Raspi I only use a 6$ Edimax usb wifi adapter...

So I thought that i could send out a WiFi 802.11n Hotspot with hostapd and receive it via my directional antenna.

But unfortunatly the results weren't quite good... I could only get the signal from a few 100 meters away and it isn't allowed in my country to send out a higher dbm...

So my question is: Do you know any better protocols that I could use with my setup? Do I need a better wifi dongle on my RaspberryPi? Or do you know anything other that could help me to increase the range of my project?

Comment: A few hundred metres from a standard WiFi adapter is pretty impressive! Given the differences in radio restrictions for different countries, you're likely to receive better answers if you can edit your question to include the country you're trying to run your setup in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [wifibroadcast](https://befinitiv.wordpress.com/wifibroadcast-analog-like-transmission-of-live-video-data/) which also uses off-the-shelf WiFi hardware :

> **Why normal wifi is a bad choice for FPV applications**
>
> - Association: Video transmitter and receiver need to be associated. If one device looses association (for example due to too weak signal strength) the video transmission stops instantly.
> - Error-free transmission: Wifi transmits either data that is correct or no data.
> - Two-way communication: Even if you are sending data only from source to sink a bi-directional data flow is required using wifi. The reason for this is that a wifi receiver needs to acknowledge the received packets.
> - One to one transfers: Unless you use broadcast frames or similar techniques a normal wifi data flow is a one to one connection.
>
> **What wifibroadcast makes different**
>
> Wifibroadcast puts the wifi cards into monitor mode. This mode allows to send and receive arbitrary packets without association.
>
> Additionally, it is also possible to receive erroneous frames (where the checksum does not match). This way a true unidirectional connection is established **which mimics the advantageous properties of an analog link**.
>
> Wifibroadcast uses Forward Error Correction to archive a high reliability at low bandwidth requirements. It is able to repair lost or corrupted packets at the receiver.